# How to secure ASP.NET REST with JQUERY client call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, rest, http-headers

I am completely new in the rest web services world and I traveled hugely articles on the web trying to implement REST webservices in ASP.NET (with in parallel a webform application in another project)

I wonder how secure WebServices ?
I set up the tutorial is explained here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call

I can call my webservices with jquery but there is no security.

Do I have to put up in a secure HTTP header? If so, how?

Another thing I wondering: a person who looks html page source code will easily find the "passkey" or "login" / "passowrd" no?

Need your help :( Thanks

EDIT :

I use this code to call my Rest service with jquery :

```
function setHeader(xhr) {
    var secretkey = "userid:uCMfSzkjue+HSDygYB5aEg==";
    var hashedUrl = secretkey;
    var hashedUrlBase64 = hashedUrl.toString();
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', hashedUrlBase64, "1234dgt");
}

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: rootWS + "ListeService/GetListeSerie" + "(" + listeId + ")",
    //data: "{'id':'" + listeId + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
                ...
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        ...
    },
    beforeSend: setHeader

});
```

and this code to my REST WS :

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetListeSerie({id})")]
public List<SeriePourListe> GetListeSerie(string id)
{
    if (!Security.AuthenticateUser())
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        return null;
    }

    //do some stuff
}

public static class Security
{
    public static bool AuthenticateUser()
    {
        WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
        string requestUri = ctx.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.ToString();
        string authHeader = ctx.IncomingRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization];
        // if supplied hash is valid, user is authenticated
        if (IsValidUserKey(authHeader, requestUri))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public static bool IsValidUserKey(string key, string uri)
    {
        string[] authParts = key.Split(':');
        if (authParts.Length == 2)
        {
            string userid = authParts[0];
            string hash = authParts[1];
            if (ValidateHash(userid, uri, hash))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static bool ValidateHash(string userid, string uri, string hash)
    {
        if (!UserKeys.Contains(userid))
            return false;
        string userkey = userid;
        byte[] secretBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userkey);
        HMACMD5 hmac = new HMACMD5(secretBytes);
        byte[] dataBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(uri);
        byte[] computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(dataBytes);
        string computedHashString = Convert.ToBase64String(computedHash);
        return computedHashString.Equals(hash);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the level of security needed. Calling from jQuery does open up your code to inspection, and can be insecure. One option is to use a proxy page which is called from jQuery, and then the proxy page communicates with the webservice. At that point the proxy page can be set up to limit access based on calling ip, host, hidden form field value, etc.

Another recommendation is to Base64 encode all request parameters. Not super secure, but entails more work for prying eyes to decode.

If your form is secure (e.g. requires a login to access), passing the current user id to the webservice and then performing a lookup to determine if that user exists within the webservice prior to performing any additional processing is the most ideal.

Webservices being what they are, are open to the public. Using credentials to access if the information returned is secure is a must. However doing from jQuery if you do not have any restrictions (e.g. login to access calling page), it will always be vulnerable.

These are only options. Hope it helps.

=================Appended Example:

***Proxy Page (.aspx)***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string result = "";


        if (Request.QueryString["srvcmethod"] != null && Request.QueryString["encodedJSONdata"] != null) {

             string decodedJSONRequest = encoder.StringFromBase64(Request.QueryString["encodedJSONdata"].ToString().Trim());
             string wsdlData = GetWebservice("ccAddressAPI", Request.QueryString["srvcmethod"].ToString().Trim(), decodedJSONRequest);

             /*
              * Existance of QueryString('callback') indicates a request initiated from JQuery AJAX on remote server
              * response must be formatted as JSONP to prevent parse failure (eg 'callback(JSON);' )
             */   
             if (Request.QueryString["callback"] != null) {
                 string jsonpCallBack = Request.QueryString["callback"];
                 result = jsonpCallBack + "(" + wsdlData + ");";
             } else {
                 result = wsdlData;
             }

             Response.Write(result);
             Response.End();
         }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs post to WebService
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="srvc">Service File Name</param>
    /// <param name="srvcMethod">Method within service to call</param>
    /// <param name="jsonData">JSON Serialized form data</param>
    /// <returns>JSON Serialized string of webservice response</returns>
    private string GetWebservice(string srvc, string srvcMethod, string jsonData) {
        string result = null;
        string wsdlData = null;
        Dictionary<string, object> obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        //--define webservice url
        string currentReq = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
        string servicepath = "/websrvc/";
        string wsdl = currentReq + servicepath + srvc + ".svc/" + srvcMethod;

        //--initiate webservice request
        try {
            byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(wsdl);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
            request.ContentType = "text/json";
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            //--retrieve/store request response
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            wsdlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logErrors(ex, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }

        return wsdlData;
    }
```

***jQuery example to call proxy page***

```
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(input){var output="";var chr1,chr2,chr3,enc1,enc2,enc3,enc4;var i=0;input=Base64._utf8_encode(input);while(i<input.length){chr1=input.charCodeAt(i++);chr2=input.charCodeAt(i++);chr3=input.charCodeAt(i++);enc1=chr1>>2;enc2=((chr1&3)<<4)|(chr2>>4);enc3=((chr2&15)<<2)|(chr3>>6);enc4=chr3&63;if(isNaN(chr2)){enc3=enc4=64}else if(isNaN(chr3)){enc4=64}output=output+this._keyStr.charAt(enc1)+this._keyStr.charAt(enc2)+this._keyStr.charAt(enc3)+this._keyStr.charAt(enc4)}return output},decode:function(input){var output="";var chr1,chr2,chr3;var enc1,enc2,enc3,enc4;var i=0;input=input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(i<input.length){enc1=this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));enc2=this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));enc3=this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));enc4=this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));chr1=(enc1<<2)|(enc2>>4);chr2=((enc2&15)<<4)|(enc3>>2);chr3=((enc3&3)<<6)|enc4;output=output+String.fro mCharCode(chr1);if(enc3!=64){output=output+String.fromCharCode(chr2)}if(enc4!=64){output=output+String.fromCharCode(chr3)}}output=Base64._utf8_decode(output);return output},_utf8_encode:function(string){string=string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var utftext="";for(var n=0;n<string.length;n++){var c=string.charCodeAt(n);if(c<128){utftext+=String.fromCharCode(c)}else if((c>127)&&(c<2048)){utftext+=String.fromCharCode((c>>6)|192);utftext+=String.fromCharCode((c&63)|128)}else{utftext+=String.fromCharCode((c>>12)|224);utftext+=String.fromCharCode(((c>>6)&63)|128);utftext+=String.fromCharCode((c&63)|128)}}return utftext},_utf8_decode:function(utftext){var string="";var i=0;var c=c1=c2=0;while(i<utftext.length){c=utftext.charCodeAt(i);if(c<128){string+=String.fromCharCode(c);i++}else if((c>191)&&(c<224)){c2=utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);string+=String.fromCharCode(((c&31)<<6)|(c2&63));i+=2}else{c2=utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);c3=utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);string+=String.fromCharCode(((c&15)<<12)|((c2&63)<<6)|(c3&63));i+=3}}return strin g}}

    var data = JSON.stringify({
            "EmployeeId": EmployeeId,
            "LoginAccountId": LoginAccountId,
            "CustomerId": CustomerId,
            "CostCentreId": CostCentreId,
            "ParentCostCentreId": ParentCostCentreId,
            "CostCentreAdministratorId": CostCentreAdministratorId,
            "UserType": UserType,
            "optionValList": optionValList
        });

        var jsondata = Base64.encode(data);
        var srvcmethod = 'initCostCentreAddressDataProvider';
        $.ajax({
            url: "[proxypageurl.aspx]",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: { "srvcmethod": srvcmethod, "encodedJSONdata": jsondata },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log({ 'XMLHttpRequest': XMLHttpRequest, 'textStatus': textStatus, 'errorThrown': errorThrown }); },
            success: function (jsonRes) {

                var json = JSON.parse(jsonRes);
        //additional processing here               
            }

        });
```

I hate to answer a question with a question, but what is the security need that you have, and what return type is the service responding with?

Calling a web method from the code behind is more self contained. The only notable difference is that the web method is typically only accessed from the calling page or application and unless you are formatting the response as JSONP, would not be available from other domains. A web service is publicly available and by default usually returns XML, but if you are returning JSON from the webservice, it also would not be available to other domains, only to yours.

So maybe format your response from the webservice as JSON? At that point, even if I know about your service I can't call it, unless you format as JSONP.

The above example uses JSONP for the jQuery as my webservice is on a seperate domain from the calling page. This can be modified to just return JSON, and the serverside logic should still work (however it is UNTESTED in that use case).

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Thanks bphillips for your help. I have edit my question to add code sample. You say "passing the current user id to the webservice" but how to do that avoiding to show userId in html/js source code ? In my sample you could easily find the secretkey "userid:uCMfSzkjue+HSDygYB5aEg==" and call my rest WS :(

Comment: Do you think best practice is to avoid call REST WS from jquery ? Is it better to call code behind webmethod or old asmx WS ? I am completly lost with all solutions...

Comment: Do you please have an example of proxy page ?

Answer (score 1):

So I have coded my own proxy and it seems to work :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static object Call(string WSUrl)
{
    // Create web client.
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    // Download string.
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Deserialize<List<object>>(client.DownloadString(WSUrl));
}
```

and it could be called like that with jquery :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:14892/common/proxy.aspx/call",
    data: "{'WSUrl':'" + rootWS + "ListeService/2/GetListeSerie" + "(" + listeId + ")" + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var result = response.d;
        var new_record = "";
        $.each(result, function (index, res) {
            new_record = serieListe(index + 1, res.Id, res.ImageUrl, res.SerieNom, res.SerieSynopsis, res.SerieUrl);
            $('#gridElementsListe').append(new_record);
        });
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        $('#msg').html("Error while calling web service,,")
    }
});
```

Hope its helps. Now I am going to add some security to my proxy as bphillips suggest to me. If you have any advises to have a good security protocol do not hesitate to share here ;)

Comment: Good Luck! These can be tricky. Please note that if you have already created the webservice, you don't need to scrap. I appended an example of a proxy page that calls your service. Think of it as a bridge between your javascript and your webservice. You can actually add a variable to the proxy page like 'string accesskey = "mysecretkey";' and then within the webservice add that as a required parameter, and if it does not exist, return an error. That way the only way you can access the service is through the proxy. Hacky but works in a pinch.

Comment: In fact I need to develop rest webservice in order to call them from my jquery ajax interface and in the futur by other web client like mobile application (android). In order to do that I have followed your advices and I have created a proxy page (to avoid to show header in the javascript, it is build in the code behind). For security I have added timestamp check like amazon and a secretkey with a SALT encoded with HMAC. In order to protect HTTP Header I think to user SSL when I will go in production environnement. What do you think about this solution ?

Comment: And all my webservices use : [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Method({id})")]  so JSON. That why I use JavaScriptSerializer in my proxy to return the same type

Comment: SSL & Salt should give you piece of mind and sounds like a solid solution. My apologies for the oversight on response format. Good luck.